# What's the easiest way to install a list of packages with latest version

Tags: apt, software-center

What's the easiest way to install a list of packages with latest version?

Using apt-cache policy or Ubuntu software center, package xxxx only has version 1.1
In Pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/), the latest version is 1.5.
I do not fancy installing from the download file (.tar.gz).
Why isn't the latest version reflected in the Ubuntu software center?

Answer (score 0):

There is often a delay between when an open source project produces a new release and when that new release is incorporated into the main ubuntu repositories.  This delay will be even greater for the LTS releases.  There are many reasons for this.  However, none of those affect your original question.

The easiest way to install a list of packages with the latest version (available in ubuntu), is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3
```

Comment: I don't find the latest versions in apt (as compared to pypi). Am I missing something? And I am behind a firewall which makes apt-get useless.